# conditionally skip transaction participant in my Jpos-template project

Tags: java, iso8583, jpos

I have multiple participants in my transaction manager config as below. I want to switch between `UAT` and `LOCAL` participants based on the object property that the current context holds (like if specific fields have specific values). How can I achieve this without having to change Java code and just modify the XML config? I am not sure if `org.jpos.transaction.participant.JSParticipant` is the way to go.

**NOTE**: I am simply using **jpos-template** project but not the **Jpos-EE**

```xml
<txnmgr class="org.jpos.transaction.TransactionManager" logger="Q2">
    <property name="queue" value="TXNMGR"/>
    <property name="sessions" value="10"/>
    <property name="max-sessions" value="100"/>

 
    <participant name="LOCAL" class="com.sanjok.qbean.RestParticipant">     

        <property name="server-signature-public-key"
                  value="***"/>
        <property name="server-encryption-public-key"
                  value="***"/>
        <property name="base64-client-signature-private-key"
                  value="***"/>
        <property name="base64-client-encryption-private-key"
                  value="***"/>               
    </participant>
    
     <participant name="UAT" class="com.sanjok.qbean.RestParticipant">     

        <property name="server-signature-public-key"
                  value="***"/>
        <property name="server-encryption-public-key"
                  value="***"/>
        <property name="base64-client-signature-private-key"
                  value="***"/>
        <property name="base64-client-encryption-private-key"
                  value="***"/>               
    </participant>

    <participant class="org.jpos.transaction.participant.SendResponse">        
    </participant>
</txnmgr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Switch` transaction participant with transaction groups like this:

```xml
<txnmgr class="org.jpos.transaction.TransactionManager" logger="Q2">
    <property name="queue" value="TXNMGR"/>
    <property name="sessions" value="10"/>
    <property name="max-sessions" value="100"/>

    <participant class="org.jpos.transaction.participant.Switch"
      logger="Q2" realm="Switch">
      <property name="txnname" value="<CONTEXT_KEY_TO_SWITCH_ON>"/> <!--1-->
      <property name="<LOCAL_VALUE>" value="LOCAL"/>                <!--2-->
      <property name="<UAT_VALUE>" value="UAT"/>                    <!--3-->
      <property name="unknown" value="<DEFAULT_ENDPOINT_OR_ERROR_GROUP>"/>  <!--4-->
    </participant>
    <group name="LOCAL">
        <participant name="LOCAL" class="com.sanjok.qbean.RestParticipant">     
...
       </participant>
     </group>    
     <group name="UAT">
       <participant name="UAT" class="com.sanjok.qbean.RestParticipant">     
...
       </participant>
    </group>
    <participant class="org.jpos.transaction.participant.SendResponse">        
    </participant>
</txnmgr>
```

1. `<CONTEXT_KEY_TO_SWITCH_ON>` is the context key that contains the value based on which you want to select the destiny.
2. `<LOCAL_VALUE>` is the value of that key that should make the transaction go to local
3. `<UAT_VALUE>` is the value of that key that should make the transaction go to UAT.
4. `<DEFAULT_ENDPOINT_OR_ERROR_GROUP>` is the endpoint (or an error group, if you want to handle it like that) where you want to go if none of the previous match. Like the `default` on a java `switch` statement.

The `Switch` transaction participant is documented in the [jPOS Programmer's Guide](http://jpos.org/doc/proguide-draft.pdf) section 9.8.1.

Basically, we are saying that if the key matches `<LOCAL_VALUE>` run group `LOCAL`, if it matches `<UAT_VALUE>` run group `UAT`, else run whatever group you define there. Participants in each group get executed right after the `Switch` participant, and before the next one.

## Select endpoint based on a property of a context object.

The OP asked in a comment to be able to select the endpoint based on a field of the request. For this we need to use code, it can be in a scripted participant.

Best option would be to use `GroovyParticipant` since it enables to precompile the script, but since the OP is not using jPOS-EE, not clear if he doesn't want to, or just isn't but willing to do.

### Using `BSHGroupSelector`.

The simplest option is to use `BSHGroupSelector` since we just need to modify the `Switch` participant for this xml:

```xml
  <participant class="org.jpos.transaction.participant.BSHGroupSelector">
    <select>
      import org.jpos.iso.*;
      ISOMsg m = context.get("REQUEST");
      String de3 = m.getString(3);
      result = (/*condition on DE3 for selecting UAT*/) ?  "UAT" : "LOCAL";
    </select>
  </participant>
```

`result` is the variable used by `GroupSelector` to determine the result of the `select` method, i.e., get the group to run.

### Using `JSParticipant`

There is no way to write a `GroupSelector` with `JSParticipant` that I know of. However, we can use a `JSParticipant` to extract field 3 to a context key. We would need to add this participant, previous to the `Switch` participant:

```xml
<participant class="org.jpos.transaction.participant.JSParticipant"
  logger="Q2" realm="js" src='cfg/extract-de3.js' />
</participant>
```

Where `cfg/extract-de3.js` has the following content:

```js
var K = Java.type("org.jpos.transaction.TransactionConstants");
var prepare = function(id, ctx) {
  //put de 3 in context under de3 key.  ctx.put("de3", 
  ctx.get("REQUEST").getString(3);
  return K.PREPARED;
}
```

The `Switch` participant definition would be as follows:

```xml
    <participant class="org.jpos.transaction.participant.Switch"
      logger="Q2" realm="Switch">
      <property name="txnname" value="de3"/> 
      <property name="<LOCAL_VALUE>" value="LOCAL"/>                
      <property name="<UAT_VALUE>" value="UAT"/>                    
      <property name="unknown" value="<DEFAULT_ENDPOINT_OR_ERROR_GROUP>"/>
    </participant>
```

Comment: I want my context key to be the value of field Id 3. If I  do `<property name="txnname" value="REQUEST"/>` participant is likely to search the group name with the whole object reference which doesn't exist.

Comment: In that case, I think you will need a "scripting" participant, like `JSParticipant` or BSHParticipant` whether to extract the field to the context and then use this, or by implementing the group selector in it.

I will update my response, but you should include that info in the question. Also, can you specify the motive of why you don't use or don't want to use jPOS-EE? With that you could use `GroovyParticipant` also.

Comment: @Sanjok, I added details of how to implement what you need using `JSParticipant` and `BSHGroupSelector`. Hope this helps.

Comment: hi  @Andrés Alcarraz, I am happy using the `JSParticipant` based solution you provided. Actually, I am doing technical research for the development of an ISO-compliant PSP solution for a startup company in Nepal. The company is not willing to go for the paid solution like JPOS-EE at least for 2-3 yrs. This is only the reason to avoid `GroovyParticipant`

Comment: @Sanjok I'm glad it worked for you, but AFAIK jPOS-EE has the same licensing model than jPOS, so if you can use one you can use the other. In fact, for using jPOS in a commercial production environment, one have to pay the license. And if I'm not wrong, that license enables you to use jPOS-EE components.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of jPOS environment variables and add the `enabled` attribute.

You can have a couple of environment variables, i.e:`uat.enabled`and `local.enabled` that you can configure like this:

```xml
<participant name="LOCAL" class="com.sanjok.qbean.RestParticipant" enabled="${local.enabled}"> 
    ...
    ...
</participant>
<participant name="UAT" class="com.sanjok.qbean.RestParticipant" enabled-"${uat.enabled}">  
   ...
   ...
</participant>
```

The you can either use YAML configurations or just environment variables (`LOCAL_ENABLED` and `UAT_ENABLED`).

This is documented in [jPOS Programmer's Guide](http://jpos.org/doc/proguide.pdf) section 3.3.